# Why is excluded volume in van der Waals equation divided by 2?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, equation-of-state

[image]

Source: [Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119568/excluded-volume-calculation-in-van-der-waals-equation)

The excluded volume calculated based on the diagram is 8 times the volume of a molecule. The volume is then **divided by 2**  to give the so-called excluded volume per molecule. Why divided by 2 only?

Obviously more than two molecules can come close together, and their assigned excluded volumes can overlap with each other, giving a smaller $b$. Is $b$ just an upper limit of excluded volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collision is predominantly a *bimolecular* act. The probability of three gas molecules simultaneously colliding is incredibly low, therefore it quite accurate to say that the excluded molar volume $b$ is overcounted by a factor of 2.